# Collection in jasper reports

Tags: java, pdf, collections, jasper-reports

I have a list of objects and I want to print them in a jasper pdf output as a table. The objects have 3 String istances. So I want something like this:

```
Obj1Str1 Obj1Str2 Obj1Str3 
.. 
Obj3Str1  .......
```

just like a table.

Can you show me what to do (xml file and java code) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` as the data source for the report.

Comment: What should I do after that ?

Comment: well, simply output the properties of the object. If I recall correctly the syntax was `${obj.property}`